# Trying to grab the correct post id from API in order to send message to only that post

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

In React Javascript - how would I send a message to a post with a specific id? Here's a sample object:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "error": null,
    "data": {
        "post": {
            "location": "Bronx, NY",
            "willDeliver": false,
            "messages": [],
            "active": true,
            "_id": "5e8d1bd48829fb0017d2233b",
            "title": "Schwinn Bicycle",
            "price": "3.88",
            "description": "This is a 19 speed bicycle, barely used.",
            "author": {
                "_id": "5e8d1a02829c8e0017c20b55",
                "username": "joe1234"
            },
            "createdAt": "2020-04-08T00:33:24.157Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-04-08T00:33:24.157Z",
            "__v": 0,
            "isAuthor": true
        }
    }
}
```

I must be grabbing the id incorrectly because the message isn't sending to the right post.
I have a useState initialized with an empty string to store the post id so I can pass it into the fetch URL request.

```
const [postId, setPostId] = useState("");
const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}/posts/${id}/messages`
```

Here's the code I have so far

```
 const sendMessage = async (token, id, content) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`${API_URL}/posts/${id}/messages`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          message: {
            content: content,
          },
        }),
      });
      const data = await response.json();
      alert("message successfully sent");
      return data;
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  };

<form
        name="message"
        onSubmit={(event) => {
          event.preventDefault();
          posts.map((post) => {
            setPostId(post._id);
          });
        }}
      <label htmlFor="content">Content: </label>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="content"
          value={messageContent}
          required
          onChange={(event) => {
            setMessageContent(event.target.value);
          }}
        />
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            sendMessage(token, postId, messageContent);
          }}
        >
          Send
        </button>
```

Thanks for any hints or help!

Comment: What is "a post"?  What does "sending a message to a post" mean?

Comment: @Pointy Sorta like a marketplace board. Sending a message to that post author. If that helps?